# Efficiency comparison for omp Fortran loop with array operation

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am comparing the efficiency for openmp in Fortran with different organizations on loop indices and whether split indices

For the given code

```
Program test
    Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64, li => int64
    use omp_lib

    integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
    
    Real( dp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: a
    Real( dp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: c

    Integer :: na
    Integer :: i, j, m
    Integer( li ) :: start, finish, rate
    Integer :: numthreads
    real(dp) :: sum_time1
    
    Write( *, * ) 'numthreads'
    Read( *, * ) numthreads

    call omp_set_num_threads(numthreads)  

    Write( *, * ) 'na'
    Read( *, * ) na
    Allocate( a ( 1:na, 1:na ) ) 
    Allocate( c ( 1:na, 1:na ) ) 

    Call Random_number( a )


    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
    do m = 1, m_iter    
      do i = 1, na
          c(i,:) = a(i,:)
      end do  
    end do  
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )
    sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate  
    Write( *, * ) 'Time for loop first index', sum_time1 

    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
      do i = 1, na
          c(:,i) = a(:,i)
      end do  
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )
    sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate  
    Write( *, * ) 'Time for loop last index', sum_time1   


    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
      do i = 1, na
        do j = 1, na
          c(i,j) = a(i,j)
        end do  
      end do  
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )
    sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate  
    Write( *, * ) 'Time for loop two index first one', sum_time1


    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
      do i = 1, na
        do j = 1, na
          c(j,i) = a(j,i)
        end do  
      end do  
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )
    sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate  
    Write( *, * ) 'Time for loop two index inner most', sum_time1    

    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
    !$omp parallel 
    !$omp do private(i)  
      do i = 1, na
        c(i,:) = a(i,:)
      end do  
    !$omp end do
    !$omp end parallel
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )
    sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate 

    Write( *, * ) 'Time for loop-omp first index', sum_time1  


    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
    !$omp parallel 
    !$omp do private(i)  
      do i = 1, na
        c(:,i) = a(:,i)
      end do  
    !$omp end do
    !$omp end parallel
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )
    sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate 

    Write( *, * ) 'Time for loop-omp last index', sum_time1  


    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
    !$omp parallel private(nthr, nstart, nend)
      nthr   = omp_get_thread_num()
      nstart = nthr * na / numthreads
      nend   = (nthr + 1) *  na / numthreads
      c(:, nstart+1:nend) = a(:, nstart+1:nend)
    !$omp end parallel
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )
    sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate 

    Write( *, * ) 'Time for omp split last index', sum_time1   

    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
    !$omp parallel private(nthr, nstart, nend)
      nthr   = omp_get_thread_num()
      nstart = nthr * na / numthreads
      nend   = (nthr + 1) *  na / numthreads
      c(nstart+1:nend, :) = a(nstart+1:nend, :)
    !$omp end parallel
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )
    sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate 

    Write( *, * ) 'Time for omp split first index', sum_time1   
  End
```

with `ifort` and `-qopenmp` `-o3` flags, I got the following results

```
  numthreads
8
 na
5000
 Time for loop first index  0.116499780000000
 Time for loop last index  3.983250000000000E-002
 Time for loop two index first one  8.187200000000000E-003
 Time for loop two index inner most  8.229439999999999E-003
 Time for loop-omp first index  3.069090000000000E-003
 Time for loop-omp last index  3.028410000000000E-003
 Time for omp split last index  1.025315000000000E-002
 Time for omp split first index  9.189559999999999E-003
```

My questions are
(i) why using two indices in loop gets faster than e.g.,  `(:,i)`

(ii) why the 'split' approach is slower than `om`p on do loop?

Comment: Why wouldn't the 'splits' take longer, seeing as there's clearly more work done in those sections? A more interesting question is why most of those sections take longer than 0 to perform, given the complete absence of any observable effect they have.

Comment: 1) after each timed loop, you should write any element of `c`, otherwise the compiler may decide to skip the entire loop, seeing that `c` is never used; 2) it has been explained to you in a previous question that when the arithmetic intensity is low (and here it is lowest possible, as for each memory unit you are performing only an assignement), parallelization leads nowhere (at least on usual hardware)